# Hibernate - HibernateTemplete saveOrUpdate Vs saveOrUpdateAll

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In HibernateTemplete class, why does saveOrUpdate provide an API of signature `saveOrUpdate(entityname, entity)`. but saveOrUpdateAll only has `saveOrUpdateAll(entities)`?

As Hibernate allows one class with multiple entities, how can I save a collection of objects of a specified entity?

For your ref.: [HibernateTemplate documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html#saveOrUpdateAll(java.util.Collection))